# Is there any trick to evaluate this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please help me to evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^{2n}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171024/please-help-me-to-evaluate-int-fracdx1x2n)

Is there any trick to evaluate

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^{2n}+1}?$$

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a try ...

Since the function is even, we have $2 \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1}dx$

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{2n}+1} dx  + \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{2n}+1} dx \\
= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (x)^{2kn} + \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^{2n}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  (-1)^kx^{-2nk} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left[\frac{(x)^{2kn+1}}{2kn+1}\right]_0^1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k \left[ \frac{x^{-2nk-2n+1}}{-2nk-2n+1}\right]_1^\infty \\
$$

So, we have $ $

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{1}{2kn+1} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{1}{2nk+2n-1} \\
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac{1}{2kn+1} + \frac{1}{2n(k+1) - 1}\right)$$

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^{2n}+1}? = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac{1}{2kn+1} + \frac{1}{2n(k+1) - 1}\right)$$

Or on complex analysis this is just special case of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37372/34351).

Comment: Try shifting some indices. Then you get $$ 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left( \frac{1}{2kn+1} + \frac{1}{2n(k+1) - 1}\right)$$


$$ 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{1}{2kn+1} - 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{1}{2n(k+1) - 1}$$

$$ 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{1}{2kn+1} - 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} \frac{1}{2nk - 1}$$

$$ 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{1}{2kn+1} + 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{-k} \frac{1}{2n(-k) + 1}$$

$$2 \sum_{k\in \Bbb Z}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{1}{2kn+1}$$

It seems sums of this form inevitably lead to trigonometric functions.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff thanks for the hint!!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff how do you know it's a trigonometric function? could you give me any links?

Comment: See the duplicate of this. It is a "partial fraction decomposition" sum over the "singularities" of the cosecant of $\pi/2n$.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff awesome!! thanks ...